# Javascript bookmarklet fails on certain sites, creates ghostly new <html> page

Tags: javascript, security, bookmarklet, bookmarks

I noticed that my Javascript bookmarklet was failing on certain sites like Google Reader and Google search results pages (and randomly on some non-Google sites). Looking at the console, I could see that, for these pages, clicking the bookmarklet did not append elements to the head/body like it normally did, but created a new document that looked like this:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Even when I reduced my bookmarklet to `javascript:alert(window.location.href);` it would create this blank page and run the bookmarklet therein, so that the alert showed `about:blank`. On most sites, this blank page is not created and the correct location is shown.

Can someone explain this? Are these sites sandboxing externally run code as a safety measure?

**UPDATE**: I currently can't reproduce this on browsers other than Chrome 17.0.932.0 dev. Please let me know if anyone else can reproduce these results on Chrome or otherwise.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your findings. Which browser is causing trouble?

Comment: Amazing. I could've sworn this was happening across browsers but now I can only reproduce it in Chrome dev. Unless anyone else can reproduce in other browsers, consider this issue on hold.

Comment: Are you testing through bookmarklets, or pastes in the location bar?

Comment: I've been testing through bookmarklets. Certainly worth a paste. Running the same code from the console works properly every time so it seems to be a navigation-away issue with the javascript: links.

Comment: +1 for ghostly web page.

Comment: Observing this behaviour for GMail pages opened Google Chrome apps.
Google Chrome 16.0.912.41
If GMail opened from gmail.com URL - works as expected.
Also, 'code' of the bookmarkled works correctly if I run it in Chrome JS console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in Google Chrome, I've filed it to their bug database: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72606

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the topmost code, i.e. the one right after `javascript:` does not return anything.

Usually this is done by wrapping everything in `void()`:

```
javascript:void(alert(window.location.href));
```

It's very odd that it breaks with `alert()` though since the function itself doesn't return anything...

Comment: Thanks, ThiefMaster. I did try it with void and had the same results. Still getting it very often in Chrome dev. Open it in FF and bookmarklet it = no problem. Have to try more in Chrome stable and report to them.

Answer (score 1):

If a `javascript:` url returns a string it will be used to create a new document:

```
javascript:'foo bar baz';
```

This can be a tough issue to debug if you don't know to watch out for it. It can crop up if you use a function that returns a string or end your bookmarklet with a line that sets a string value:

```
javascript: a = prompt('foo bar baz'); b = a;
```

A simple solution is to use a closure:

```
javascript:(function(){ var a; a = prompt('foo bar baz'); window.b = a}());
```

An alternative is to end with `void 0;`

```
javascript: a = prompt('foo bar baz'); b = a; void 0;
```