# Why are Javascript bookmarklets wrapped in closures?

Tags: javascript, function, closures, bookmarklet

Why are Javascript bookmarklets wrapped in closures?
I wouldn't think someone would put an unnamed function in there for no reason.

I have read quite a few explanations on closures, but I still don't feel that i've grasped the whole concept.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Its not a closure, actually, just a local scope.

Comment: Also, anonymous function use eliminates the need to suppress last return value with `void` operator.

Comment: @user539484 could you elaborate on your last comment, with an example? Thanks!

Comment: Try `javascript:a='HAI'` in the address

Comment: Or better see this doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void#JavaScript_URIs

Comment: @user539484 Oh thanks, didn't know that. So this method: `javascript:(function(){var x=10; })()` ...would work, but this: `javascript: var x=10;` ...would attempt to go to that URL!

Comment: yep, if return value isnt undefined, bookmarklet will destroy a page

Comment: @OnTheFly Does that mean that using `javascript:void(my code)` would work as well? Does that leak variables? (If it works, I would love to see that as an answer to this question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not contaminate the global scope by executing a function after creation.

```
(function(){var x=10; })()
alert(window.x) // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

This prevents variables in the bookmarklet from leaking into the page.

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons:

### contamination

The first is for preventing global contamination for any of the variables needed for the bookmarklet. Using a closure means that `var a` wont add `window.a` to the global context. Additionally, using a named function would add it to the global namespace. `function a() {...}` would add `window.a`.

### accidental DOM recreation

The second is to avoid accidentally recreating the DOM by returning a string. Any `javascript:` url where a string is returned will create a brand new DOM using the contents of the string as the source.

Answer (score 0):

Because the folks who are making them are good citizens of the web :) and don't want to step over the actual page's JavaScript accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

A mixture of scope conflicts and return policy.

[zzzzBov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8169093/871580) in this thread covers the main issues succinctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally to avoid polluting the global namespace, it's also known as the Module Pattern as described by Ben Cherry: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth